# Can my HTML5 canvas effects run on iPhone or Android?

Tags: iphone, android, html, canvas

I design a HTML5 canvas effects homepage on my site http://catfan.me

You can click the sky and add a cloud, and It`s able to show the fps.

It runs perfect on HTML5 supported browser, such as Chrome, FireFox, Safari, IE9..

But i do not know if it run on iPhone, iPad or Android mobile phone. I didn`t have this devices.

Can anyone to help me to test? Or is there any way to test the HTML5 effects running on iPad? Such as iOS or Android Emulator?

Comment: Kitten doesn't like your clouds... unlimited FPS makes kitten unhappy... kitten is going to throw that hawt CPU after you! Seriously, please limit the FPS, using 60% of my CPU isn't fun, imagine every website would do that...

Comment: I agree with "Kitten", I suggest you use `setTimeout` with a delay above 10ms (e.g. 33ms :- 30fps max).

Answer (score 3):

This is not a programming related question... anyway, just tested on iPhone and Android: it didn't work for both. If you want to test by your self, just [install the android emulator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjD5any2C8Q).

Answer (score 2):

There are various iPhone and Android emulators available if you google, but I prefer the ones that come with XCode for iPhone/Mac and the official SDK for android.

If you don't have access to a mac you can emulate iphone support pretty good through Safari for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with dolphin browser HD and the clouds moved around and more popped up when I clicked them.

Answer (score 1):

Both Android (2.0+) and [iOS4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DplCnbwFD2c) supports HTML5 in some way or another, so your page will probably be displayed correctly though it might be a little laggy. You may want to let W3C finish their work on HTML5 before implementing it on your website, if you want it to run perfectly on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to reply. But I was wondering the same thing so I tried it on my Android 2.1 and it worked. When I touched a cloud and it's split into 2 of them and displayed the corresponding message. This might be a good example: html5 canvas would be way to go rather than SVG or Silverlight Graphics.